# Converting a large CSV file to a Pickle file with Pandas chunk by chunk

Tags: python, pandas, csv, bigdata, pickle

I have a large CSV file and I am trying to convert it into a Pickle file. The file is very large and so I am processing the file chunk by chunk. The current code I have is below.

```py
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm

def pickel_convert(source, dest, chunksize = 10000):
    print("Converting {} to {}".format(source, dest))
    print("Chunksize: {}".format(chunksize))
    reader = pd.read_csv(source, chunksize = chunksize)
    open(dest, 'w').close() # clear the file
    with open(dest, "ab") as pickel_file:
        for chunk in tqdm(reader):
            chunk.to_pickle(dest)
    print()

pickel_convert('unzipped-data/test_data.csv', 'data-pickles/test_data.pkl')
```

This code executes without any errors, however when I try to read the Pickle files into a dataframe there are only 10 000 rows, and original the CSV file has over 10 million rows. This was confirmed with the following code:

```py
import pandas as pd

# read datasets from pickel file
test_data = pd.read_pickle('data-pickles/test_data.pkl')

# check the shape of the datasets
print("test_data shape: {}".format(test_data.shape))
```

Is it possible to do this on a chunk-by-chunk basis, and if so how?

Comment: parquet might be a better file format here. Dask could handle writing to parquet like this easily.